# no "current_page_item" class being added to top level nav item

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

If you go to [www.lindysez.com](http://www.lindysez.com) and click on the top level navigation links, you'll notice that position presence is indicated by a slightly darker background (same as hover state). This works for each of the links EXCEPT "Tips & Techniques".

If I look under the hood, I noticed that the "current_page_item" class isn't being added to the parent

of the "Tips & Techniques" menu item when you go to http://www.lindysez.com/tips

Also, curiously enough, when on the tips page, the parent

of the "Blog" navigation item gets the class "current_page_parent", which is neither expected nor desired. This is harmless from a UI standpoint, but probably an indication what the underlying problem might be.

Anyone know why the "Tips & Techniques" menu item isn't getting the "current_page_item" class once selected?

---

### Update: Directed @user2019515's comment below

Thanks for the nudge in this direction, it does seem like I could create a workaround that would fix this. Couple things however.

1. This treats the symptom of the problem rather than the root. I'd like to figure out how to get wp to just add the "current_page_item" class natively. Any idea what's causing this? I think it may also be related to another problem I'm having which involves "tips" not showing in the RSS feed. I posted another question about that, but haven't seen any answers... 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980846/custom-post-type-not-showing-up-in-wordpress-rss-feed
2. Even as a workaround, I'd rather try to avoid a solution that relies on hard coded "menu-item-##". My development and production servers both have different ID#'s. I know I can account for this, but I hope there's a better, scalable workaround.
3. The code you provided didn't work for me, not that I can find any fault in it, nor are there any errors. Seems like it should work, but just doesn't. I even tried creating a very simple version that would add a class to all the items, but this too isn't executing. Here's that code.

   ```
   function add_class_to_wp_nav_menu($classes, $item)
   {
       $classes[] = 'classy-class';
       return $classes;
   }
   add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_wp_nav_menu', 10, 2);
   ```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Tips page is a post archive page, it shows posts rather than a normal page that's why the blog was being highlighted. You can easily fix this issue by adding the following custom CSS to your `style.css` file.

```
.post-type-archive-tips .menu-item-23{
    background:url(images/nav-hover.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. When I'm on the tips page, the parent <li> of the "Tips & Techniques" link has a class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23" which is exactly the same classes it gets if I'm on the "Recipes" page. I appreciate your trying, and I see where you were going with this, but I'd really like to figure out how to get the "current_page_item" class to be added. The "tips" is a custom post type just as "recipes" is, so they should both work the same I'd think.

Comment: I'll add a new answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over your menu, by default the current page class is added to the blog page because in the end the custom posts.

```
//Change current_page_parent for custom post type
function remove_parent_classes($class)
{
  // check for current page classes, return false if they exist.
  return ($class == 'current_page_item' || $class == 'current_page_parent' || $class == 'current_page_ancestor'  || $class == 'current-menu-item') ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

function add_class_to_wp_nav_menu($classes)
{
  switch (get_post_type()) {
    case 'portfolio':
      // we're viewing a custom post type, so remove the 'current_page_xxx and current-menu-item' from all menu items.
      $classes = array_filter($classes, "remove_parent_classes");

      // add the current page class to a specific menu item (replace ###).
      if (in_array('menu-item-14', $classes)) {
         $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
      }
      break;
    case 'tips':
      // we're viewing a custom post type, so remove the 'current_page_xxx and current-menu-item' from all menu items.
      $classes = array_filter($classes, "remove_parent_classes");

      // add the current page class to a specific menu item (replace ###).
      if (in_array('menu-item-23', $classes)) {
         $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
      }
      break;
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_wp_nav_menu');
```

There's just one custom post type in the function, but I'm sure you can figure out how to add more. Got any questions, feel free to leave a comment! :)

Comment: I have a comment which is too long to leave as a comment, so I'll update the original case with this info. Please see above